# How to make a column value appear only once using Knockout?

Tags: javascript, jquery, knockout.js

I am using Knockout to generate a table that loops through a list of objects; however, there is a column that I only want to appear once. In the example below:

```
Group | Component | Description |
---------------------------------
A     | Comp 1    | Desc 1      |
A     | Comp 2    | Desc 2      |
B     | Comp 3    | Desc 3      |
B     | Comp 4    | Desc 4      |
```

I would want the final output to look like this:

```
Group | Component | Description |
---------------------------------
A     | Comp 1    | Desc 1      |
      | Comp 2    | Desc 2      |
B     | Comp 3    | Desc 3      |
      | Comp 4    | Desc 4      |
```

Is there a way to do this via jQuery or some other framework?

**Edit**

Sample code:
https://jsfiddle.net/on6Lby1c/

Comment: You mean that you don't want consecutive duplicate values to appear in that column? (The actual column appears once either way.) If the table is generated via some form of loop it's not that hard to add a variable to remember the previous "Group" value and an if test to only output the value when different to the previous.

Comment: How is table generated?....could use `rowspan`. Provide a [mcve]

Comment: @nnnnnn yeah sorry that's what I meant. I want the value to appear only once when it's already been displayed.

Comment: @charlietfl I'm using knockout data binding to loop through my list, I don't know how many items there are in each group so I don't know what number to put in `rowspan`.

Comment: so map the data first into the groups and then you know how many are in each group

Comment: Can you [edit] your question to show the code in question? (It it HTML with Knockout directives?) There could be a reasonably simple way to modify your existing code to get the desired effect, if you would just *show* the existing code... (You could also modify the final HTML with just a few lines of jQuery, but it would be better to fix the original.)

Comment: I edited my question with a sample code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Anoops answer works but I personally prefer to avoid inline calculations.
As such you can offload this calculation to a function and bind to that on the viewmodel via `$parent`.

Don't forget to sort if you want 0 duplicates :)

```js
var vm = function() {
  var data = new ko.observableArray([
    { group: 'A', component: 'Component 1', description: 'Description 1' },
    { group: 'A', component: 'Component 2', description: 'Description 2' },
    { group: 'B', component: 'Component 3', description: 'Description 3' },
    { group: 'B', component: 'Component 4', description: 'Description 4' },
  ]);

  function groupValue(index) {
   var underlyingArray = data();
    if(index == 0)
      return underlyingArray[0].group;

    return underlyingArray[index-1].group == underlyingArray[index].group 
     ? "" : underlyingArray[index].group;
  }

  return {
    data: data,
    groupValue: groupValue
  }
}

ko.applyBindings(new vm());
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.2.0/knockout-min.js"></script>
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr><th>Group</th><th>Component</th><th>Description</th></tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody data-bind="foreach: data">
        <tr>
            <td data-bind="text: $parent.groupValue($index())"></td>
            <td data-bind="text: component"></td>
            <td data-bind="text: description"></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/fv9x3s20/

Comment: Thanks. This definitely seems like a better solution that an inline calculation.

Answer (score 0):

Change the code as below, It will work.

```html
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr><th>Group</th><th>Component</th><th>Description</th></tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody data-bind="foreach: myObj">
        <tr>
            <td data-bind="text: $index()-1 >= 0?  ($parent.myObj[$index()-1].group == group? '' : group):group"></td>
            <td data-bind="text: component"></td>
            <td data-bind="text: description"></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Updated fiddle,

https://jsfiddle.net/on6Lby1c/1/